# Using filter and lambda in a list of lists

Tags: python, list, lambda, filter

I working with a list of lists. Each of those lists are the same -- they contain title, url and some additional statistics (always in the same order).

---

[image: My list of lists]

I would like to create a function `find_title`, which takes the wanted title and returns the whole list (with title, url and statistics). That's my attempt

```
def find_title(title, ls):
    return(list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == title, ls)))
```

However it doesn't work, it returns nothing. That's probably because `x[0]` denotes only the first element in the big list. How can it be fixed?

Edit. That's a part of ls:

```
[['Der Vagabund und das Kind (1921)',
  'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0012349/',
  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 ['Goldrausch (1925)',
  'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0015864/',
  0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 ['Metropolis (1927)',
  'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0017136/',
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Comment: `title in x[0]`?

Comment: is there any specific reason you are working with nested lists?

Comment: @ChayanBansal in fact there isn't. I need to do a lot of manipulation with that data and I created a list of lists from a data frame rows.

Comment: you should have directly extracted the required information from dataframe. It would have been more efficient and simple

Comment: Your solution should work. Could you please print your `ls` and share it?

Comment: @ChayanBansal can you provide and example how to extract a data frame row with a certain title? I tried but I failed.

Comment: share your data, I mean a sample

Comment: @Hendrra your function should work. Bare in mind that it returns list of lists so maybe this is your issue...

Comment: @Hendrra I think that your issue is with the provided title. Try to print it in the first line of your function to check if the value is the same as you expect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly extract the information from dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['Der Vagabund und das Kind (1921)',
  'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0012349/',
  0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 ['Goldrausch (1925)',
  'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0015864/',
  0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
 ['Metropolis (1927)',
  'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0017136/',
  0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]])

print(df[df[0] =='Goldrausch (1925)'])
```

Comment: This is basically one line answer to your question